# ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android - Versions found: 29.0.2, 31.0.0 - Version supported: Not Found

Tags: react-native, android-studio, sdk

im trying to conect react native to an emulator and because I cant successfully launch it, I run

```
npx @react-native-community/cli doctor
```

but it gave me this warning

```
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: 29.0.2, 31.0.0
   - Version supported: Not Found
```

these are the things that I have tried
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
Version supported: Not Found
```

this has been resolved by downloading the react native cli

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: I continue to get this error despite doing. npm install -g react-native-cli.

Comment: i remember i just reinstalled the whole thing at the end cause using  "npm install -g react-native-cli" is just like slapping a bandaid on a bigger issue

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio installs the latest Android SDK by default. Building a React Native app with native code, however, requires the `Android 12 (S)` SDK in particular. Additional Android SDKs can be installed through the SDK Manager in Android Studio.

To do that, open Android Studio, click on "More Actions" button and select "SDK Manager".
Select the "SDK Platforms" tab from within the SDK Manager, then check the box next to "Show Package Details" in the bottom right corner. Look for and expand the `Android 12 (S)` entry, then make sure the following items are checked:

```
- Android SDK Platform 31

- Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image or Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image
```

Next, select the "SDK Tools" tab and check the box next to "Show Package Details" here as well. Look for and expand the `Android SDK Build-Tools` entry, then make sure that `31.0.0` is selected.

Finally, click "Apply" to download and install the Android SDK and related build tools.